# Scale Up Flipclock.js

Tags: css, flipclock

I've got a site which uses flipclock.js. I've been going through a bit of trouble making it larger, so it takes up more space on the page.

Does anyone know how to scale it up, or make it larger?

Comment: Can you share any URL or snippet here? So we can understand how can you scale it up...

Comment: Hi @CodeGator the url I'm using for reference is https://codepen.io/sarus/pen/xjKEZq?editors=0100

Comment: You can do it like this...
.flip-clock-wrapper {
    transform: scale(1.5);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clock adapts based on the font-size. If you change the font size in the codepen you provided in the comments ( https://codepen.io/sarus/pen/xjKEZq?editors=0100 ) the whole clock scales up/down. You can also adjust border-radius, gap and the dot size individually.

Basically, the first 4 SASS variables are intended to be changed:

```
// 
// ------------------------- FlipClock
// 
$clock-flip-font-size: 200px
$clock-flip-border-radius: 8px
$clock-digit-gap: 40px
$clock-dot-size: 20px
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this sass and you're done....

```
.countdown.flip-clock-wrapper 
  transform: scale(1.5)
```